# CSS-GRID row height issue

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm having a hard time with css-grid row heights.

This is what i currently have: 
[Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgAmF.png)

What I want is the result below where 1 and 2 are the same heights.

[Result i wish to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f32ZA.png)

Would it be possible to specify row heights without a hardcoded value like `height: 500px`

But instead of hardcoded values use fractions or something?

This is the code i have for my grid(items)

```
.o-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 0.5fr 2fr 1fr 1fr 2fr;
  height: 100%;

  &__header {
    grid-column: 1/5;
    grid-row: 1;
  }

  &__statistics {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 2;
  }

  &__burndown {
    grid-column: 2 / span 2;
    grid-row: 2 / 5;
  }

  &__fastlane {
    grid-column: 4 / 5;
    grid-row: 2 / -1;
    margin: -20px 0 0 0;
  }

  &__today {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 3;
  }

  &__beer {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 4;
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looks fine to me when put into a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Orvbex. Could you get your full code into a codepen that highlights the issue? Rather than just pictures?

Comment: @Logiwan992 Thanks for your reply, I guess i gave the today section a little to much padding which stretches the container. Putting all this in a codepen would be dificult because it's a Vue application

EDIT: Actually when i give the __today section in your codepen a pedding the rows height adjusts correctly, so something is not working quite right

Comment: You don't have to put your entire application in a codepen, just enough to where the issue starts appearing. You are able to include external libraries in codepen if you are using any for the css.

Comment: @Logiwan992 The thing is I can't reproduce it in codepen It just seems to work there. Im not getting it atm